# Generating Degree of a subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

This is example 1.8.38 of Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I. The statement is that (after some translation) $I_X(d)$ is globally generated, where $X\subset \mathbb{P}^r$ is is a variety of degree $d$ and dimension $n$. The explanation given there is that we consider a linear subspace $\Lambda$ of dimension $r-n-1$, and consider the cone of $X$ centred at $\Lambda$, denoted by $C_\Lambda(X)$. Then this is a hypersurface of degree $d$. If we varying $\Lambda$, the resulting hypersurface generating $I_X(d)$.

My question is the last step. $I_X(d)$ means the degree $d$ polynomial, which gives a hypesurface, vanishing (contaning) $X$. Why we can conclude it is generated by global section there? I do not think I fully understand generated by global section geometrically very well.

Comment: Geometrically, global sections of $I_X(d)$ generates it means, given any point $p\in\mathbb{P}^r$, the given sections generate the stalk at $p$. In this particular case, this is essentially same as saying the intersection of all these degree $d$ hypersurfaces is precisely $X$. (Technically, one should check this scheme-theoretically, not just as sets.)

Comment: @Mohan Thank you very much. So suppose that it is not generated by global section, then (scheme-theoretical) intersection should be larger than the variety we have at some point. Is my understanding right? Also is there any reference or reading for it?